# how do I make wxWidgets (using golang) repaint window on MacOS?

Tags: go, wxwidgets

Here's some sample code that puts a Gauge on the screen and make the progress bar increase 1 value every second. On MacOS I don't see the progress bar update unless I drag the window around or resize it manually with the mouse. Any idea how to force the whole thing to repaint? I'm calling f.Refresh() and f.Update()

```
package main

import "github.com/dontpanic92/wxGo/wx"
import "time"

var g wx.Gauge

type MyFrame struct {
    wx.Frame
}

func (f *MyFrame) startUpload() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        g.SetValue(g.GetValue() + 1)
        f.Refresh()
        f.Update()
    }
}

func NewMyFrame() MyFrame {
    f := MyFrame{}
    f.Frame = wx.NewFrame(wx.NullWindow, -1, "Test Thread")
    mainSizer := wx.NewBoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    g = wx.NewGauge(f, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.NewSize(600, 40), 0)
    f.SetSizer(mainSizer)
    mainSizer.Add(g, 100, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 50)
    f.Layout()
    go f.startUpload()
    return f
}

func main() {
    wx1 := wx.NewApp()
    f := NewMyFrame()
    f.Show()
    wx1.MainLoop()
    return
}
```

Update: I've been reading http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html and I'm trying code like:

```
b := wx.NewPaintEvent()
f.GetEventHandler().QueueEvent(b)
```

instead of calling Refresh and Update but my wx.NewPaintEvent doesn't do anything. Maybe I'm making the wx.NewPaintEvent wrong? Or I'm adding it to the wrong EventHandler?

Comment: What's OSX version? What's wx version? Can you build wx and try the dialog sample?

Comment: 10.11.6, master from github.com/dontpanic92/wxGo/wx which is wxWidgets-3.1.0, yeah the sample included builds fine but does not have any threads like my example

Comment: are you trying to work with the gauge and the window from the secondary thread?

Comment: yeah, i'm just trying to make the gauge grow slowly over the course of like 30 seconds to simulate progress in another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

author of wxGo fixed it:

https://github.com/dontpanic92/wxGo/issues/10

```
  wx.Bind(f, wx.EVT_THREAD, func(e wx.Event) {
    threadEvent := wx.ToThreadEvent(e)
    the_gauge.SetValue(threadEvent.GetInt())
  }, UPLOAD_WORKER_ID)
```

then in the thread:

```
threadEvent := wx.NewThreadEvent(wx.EVT_THREAD, UPLOAD_WORKER_ID)
threadEvent.SetInt(50)
f.QueueEvent(threadEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, doing anything with GUI objects from the non-main (i.e. not the one that initialized the library) thread is not supported by wxWidgets.

The usual workaround is to post an event to the main thread asking it to update the widget instead of doing it directly in the worker thread. In C++ this can be done easily and elegantly using [CallAfter()](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2013/01/about-benefits-of-procrastination.html), but I don't know enough about Go and wxGo to show you an example of doing it in this language.

Comment: thank you, I've been reading http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html over and over but I can't get my wxPaintEvent that I add to to my Frame's wxEventHandler to do anything.

Comment: You can't generate `wxPaintEvent`s directly, this is the job for the underlying GUI itself. You really do need to call `Refresh()` from the main thread.